# Intersection over union vs sensitivity

Tags: sensitivity-specificity, image-segmentation, jaccard-similarity

In the context of segmentation, what is the difference between IoU and sensitivity? It sounds to me like they describe the same formula in different contexts but I might be wrong.

- When true positivies are denoted as TP and false negatives as FN, sensitivity is TP/(TP+FN).
- IoU is intersection/union, but intersection is "both the ground truth and the predictions are true" which sounds like TP, and union is "either is true" which sounds like TP+FN.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

IoU is defined as TP/(TP+FN+FP). On the other hand, Sensitivity, yes TP/(TP+FN).

THe key difference, let's say the segmenter predicts everything into 1, the whole cube or region.

Since, the whole region always covers the target region, the Sensitivity is 1, however IoU will be not 1, since there are a lot of FP.

Think about oversegmentation case, then, the difference between IoU and Sensitivity will be clear.